# How to control image size in menu?

Tags: android, image, menu

I have menu with images. I have big images 72x72.
In activity layout I'm using:

```
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:layout_width="55dip"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" - this works fine.
```

But in menu items I don't know how to do the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
 menu.findItem(R.id.menu_Help).setIcon(resizeImage(R.drawable.ic_noaction_help,108,108));
    return true;
}

private Drawable resizeImage(int resId, int w, int h)
{
      // load the origial Bitmap
      Bitmap BitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
      int width = BitmapOrg.getWidth();
      int height = BitmapOrg.getHeight();
      int newWidth = w;
      int newHeight = h;
      // calculate the scale
      float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
      float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
      // create a matrix for the manipulation
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
      Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapOrg, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);
      return new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An improvement to Kostadin's answer above is to save memory by avoiding the creation of the first bitmap he calls `BitmapOrg`, by using the approach described http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Answer (score -1):

Inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
menu.findItem(R.id.action_overflow).setIcon(resizeImage(R.mipmap.more,72,72));
```