# how to increase icon size in icon in menu_main.xml

Tags: android

I have the following items in menu_main.xml:-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="net.ossrs.yasea.demo.MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="200" app:showAsAction="never" />
  <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:menuCategory="system"
      android:title="action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        />

    <item android:id="@+id/original_filter" android:title="Original"  app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/beauty_filter" android:title="Beauty" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/cool_filter" android:title="Cool" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/early_bird_filter" android:title="Early Bird" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/evergreen_filter" android:title="Evergreen" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/n1977_filter" android:title="N1977" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/nostalgia_filter" android:title="Nostalgia" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/romance_filter" android:title="Romance" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/sunrise_filter" android:title="Sunrise" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/sunset_filter" android:title="Sunset" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/warm_filter" android:title="Warm" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/tender_filter" android:title="Tender" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/toast_filter" android:title="Toast" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/valencia_filter" android:title="Valencia" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/walden_filter" android:title="Walden" app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

My android icon is to small . So I want to increase the size of my android icon............
i am giving the android:height and android:width in my icon but nothing is changed.

Comment: You need to add bigger picture

Comment: I also added the big size image but nothing is happen

Comment: what size image you adding? should be 72x72 for xxhdpi folder

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do it programmatically within `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the Activity that contains the menu by manipulating the icon as a drawable.

[Here is an example from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278959/how-to-control-image-size-in-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Make Below entry in dimens.

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```